# Unsure how to check which part of the Query is executed in case of SELECT(CASE .. END)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So in my database, I have 4 separate tables. The primary table, consists of an ID, name, and some other information. The main ID is referenced by the other 2 tables. For example, Table 1 is a list of students with STUDENT ID/ Name/Age. Table 2 consists of STUDENT ID/  Information Pertaining to Science Majors and Table 3 consists of STUDENT ID/ Information Pertaining to Psychology Majors. Table 4 contains additional information related to Psychology Majors

I need to write a PHP page, which receives a STUDENT ID, and first prints the student Name/Age, then,  if it is present in Table 2, it needs to print a different set of information and if it is is present in Table 3, it needs to print a different set of information(And if it selects Table 3, I need to print information from Table 4).

- The way I went about doing this is, first, I wrote an SQL Query to print the generic information common in both cases.
- For the second part of the question, I planned on writing an SQL Query in the following manner:

```
SELECT( CASE WHEN :variable IN
         (SELECT student_id from Table 2) 
          THEN
          ......
          ELSE
         ...
        END)
```

My question is, how do I check whether the ID was in my first case of the query or the second, so that I can print the information accordingly. Also, if the ID was in the second query, I need to further print information from the new table. How would I go about checking for the same?

Update: Simplified question. If my ID is in table 2, I select Columns: A, B ,C. If it is in table 3, I select Columns: D, E, F. After the query, I need to print either A, B, C or D, E, F based on which Table the ID was in. How do I go about checking the same

Comment: Perhaps use `INNER JOIN`? We can't help you without seeing the tables, perhaps update your question to include the table names and columns.

Comment: @Jaquarh I don't think you understood my question. I have no issue with regard to my queries. Suppose I use the SELECT(Case-- End query), I would have  selected different columns for both cases. So Based on the case executed, I need to echo"print"// The correct columns. I'm not sure how to go about checking this

Comment: Perhaps use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) on the data? Your question is unclear, please read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We cannot copy this into our own environment.

Comment: @Jaquarh I updated the question with some additional information. Maybe that might help

Comment: Do columns ABC have the same data type as DEF? Your query won't work out if A is an int  and D is a time stamp, for example.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is statically defined in its list of output fields. If you need the fields as stated in the question, you would have to provide a list of fields with aliased names to represent the different tables, something in the line of:

```
SELECT table1_studentname, table2_studentname, etc
( CASE WHEN :variable IN
     (SELECT student_id from Table 2) 
      THEN
      ......
      ELSE
     ...
    END) as table3_studentname
```

And probably you will have to refactor your query to fulfill these conditions by using joins instead of case statements.

Essentially in the answer of a query you should not be really concerned where it came from, or if that is relevant, it is more traditional to fire multiple queries (one by one for example, check if conditions are met, and then conditionally execute the next one).

Comment: With regard to the last paragraph of your answer, how can I use a query to check whether the ID is in table 1, such that it returns true or false and I can use multiple queries that way to print the necessary information.

Comment: You could use the case statement to return a true/false (or more detailed message which you can inspect, like "table 1 had id") for 1 field, and a second field just with the ID, thus limiting the case statement, and being able to use joins for the rest (many solutions are possible, it always depends on the use case)